# Using Dart flutter best way to add entries to a map

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a form that i am validating and want to easily add entries to the map the best way i have right now is:

```
Widget emailField() {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (newValue) {
        formValues.addEntries({'email': newValue}.entries);
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (!value!.contains('@')) {
          return 'Invalid email address';
        }
        return null;
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        label: Text('Login Email'),
        hintText: 'you@example.com',
      ),
    );
  }
```

But it seems like their should be an easier way. Maybe it is because I don't get the .entries syntax I was expecting something like `.push` OR `.add`??

But it seems like their should be an easier way. Maybe it is because I don't get the .entries syntax I was expecting something like `.push` OR `.add`??

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
    formValues.addEntries({'email': newValue}.entries);
```

you just do

```
    formValues['email'] = newValue;
```